# A more efficient way to Retrieve records into a JSON array in MySQL? C

Tags: mysql, c, json, database, memory-management

I am using MySQL in my C application. I have created a function

```
GetInDB(char *query, cJSON **json){...
```

that will allocate the json as a json array, query the db, and store the records in the array. The problem is that it seems difficult to quickly get the field name of each column in a table. Since I don't know the string length of each name in advance, I have to iterate through the results and dynamically allocate (!) a string that is large enough to hold each one. Then, I have to iterate through each record. Is there a better way?

```
int GetInDB(const char *query, cJSON **json)
{
    if(*json != NULL){
        cJSON_Delete(*json);
    }
    *json = cJSON_CreateArray();
    if (mysql_query(mysqldb, query))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysqldb));
        return -1;
    }
    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(mysqldb);
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(mysqldb));
        return -1;
    }
    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    int i;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_FIELD *field;
    char *Columns[num_fields];
    int which = 0;
    while((field = mysql_fetch_field(result)))
    {
        Columns[which] = (char*)malloc(strlen(field->name)+1);
        strcpy(Columns[which], field->name);
        which++;
    }
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
    {
        cJSON *obj = cJSON_CreateObject();
        for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
        {
            cJSON_AddStringToObject(obj, Columns[i], row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
        }
        cJSON_AddItemToArray(*json,obj);
    }
    mysql_free_result(result);
    for(i=0; i<num_fields; i++){
        free(Columns[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```